# Rectangular picture shrunk to square in mobile (while looking in proportion in desktop)

Tags: css, media-queries, html-email

The content of the image in the email is fed using dynamic data. The image is a book cover which is most of the time square and sometimes rectangular (height bigger than width).

The code shows both types of images correctly in the desktop mail client but when we open the email in iPhone, the rectangular images are also shrunk to squares.

A sample rectangular image in desktop:

[image]

The same image viewed on iPhone:

[image]

The `<img>` (contained in a `<td>`) has the following code in the email template:

```
<td style="padding: 22px 11px 0px; text-align: center">
<img src="http://placehold.it/170" width="163" alt="alt_text" border="0" class="fluid img221" style="vertical-align: middle; height: auto; background: #dddddd; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; color: #555555;">
</td>
```

As we see in the above code, `<img>` inherits a class called "fluid" which has the following properties in the media queries:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

      .fluid {
        max-width: 100% !important;
        height: auto !important;
        margin-left: auto !important;
        margin-right: auto !important;
      }
...
}
```

I am not a front-end person. Can I get some help on why I get squares in mobile devices?

**UPDATE:**

I also found the following CSS under the media queries section above:

```
.img221 {
        width: 221px !important;
        height: 221px !important;
      }
```

The `img221`, I noticed was mentioned in the `<img>`'s class attribute.

Comment: are there other `<td>`'s in the row with the image?

Comment: @zgood no, that is the only `<td>` in its container `<tr>`.

Comment: Can you share a link to the working web page?

Comment: @AndyHoffman this is an email template.

Comment: Does it help if you set the `img` to `display: block;`?

Comment: try taking out the max-width : 100% in .fluid

Comment: The code you're sharing is not the code from your email. You're sharing a placeholder image and not the actual image or your html email code. From this we can't tell what the dimensions of the original image are online. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and update your question. In short: do not write an essay explaining what you want to do, **show your code** so we can see what have you have tried so far.

Comment: @gwally I'm sorry if the code is insufficient. As I said in the first line of the question "The content of the image in the email is fed using dynamic data." So the data is replaced at the time of send. So I can only have the code on the receiving end. I can paste code of the Web version of the email but that will not be much of help because this question concerns the mobile version.

Comment: @GifCo this unfortunately did not make a difference.

Comment: Since you refuse to share your html, I know you really do not want help, even though you know how StackOverflow works. But out of curiosity, does the same thing happen with your email template and a placeholder image?

Comment: @gwally yes, I just uploaded a book image from the library. Looks good on the desktop but still square in mobile.

Comment: @gwally what other parts of the code should I share with you? I am sharing the parts related to the problem. The template code is rather big.

Comment: @gwally please take a look at the update part of the question. Appreciate that.

Comment: Well there you go!!! You are setting width and height to the same size which is giving you a square image. Remove everything to do with setting height.

Comment: change the height for `.img221` to auto and it will work perfectly. `height: auto !important;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your .img221 class you set height and width to the same size which is forcing the image to be square. Change the class to this

```
.img221 {
    width: 221px !important;
 }
```

Comment: True. I realized this last night and changed it and it seems to be working fine. Thank you for the spot-on answer.